# Jquery Cycle 2 double pager

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I have two jQuery Cycles Version 2. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ 
I want to have one navigation (#nav) to control both of the cycles. I know it is still BETA, so maybe it isn't possible yet..

```
    <script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.scrollVert.js"></script>

    <div class="cycle-slideshow"
        data-cycle-fx="scrollVert"
        data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
        data-cycle-timeout="0"
        data-cycle-pager="#nav">
        <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/29oocgm.jpg" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>1</a>" />
        <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/o602sz.jpg" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>2</a>" />
        <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/qntoxc.jpg" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>3</a>" />
    </div>
    ​<br />
    <br />
    <div class="cycle-slideshow"
        data-cycle-fx="scrollVert"
        data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
        data-cycle-timeout="0"
        data-cycle-pager="#nav">
        <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/29oocgm.jpg" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>1</a>" />
        <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/o602sz.jpg" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>2</a>" />
        <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/qntoxc.jpg" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>3</a>" />
    </div>
    <div id="nav"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hfjXd/

Answer (score 0):

Iøm not sure I understand exctly what you mean but if you just use:

```
data-cycle-prev=".prev"
data-cycle-next=".next"
```

on both of the Cycles it should just do it.

check this example: view-source:http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php
and this one: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php